# Select field_name base on the table id from each of the list

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem.
I want to show field_name at my query 'select .. from .. where' clause.

In my logging table, the table only keep the `[date],[table_id],[field_id]` .. fields, i need to show the `'field_name'` as well in my select but there is no any other table that i can 'join' to get the `[field_name]` based on `[field_id]` in my `'select .. from'`. As I search from google it seems I can get the field_name from SQL system called `'sys.columns'` table. but that is too complicated for my SQL level because this sys.coloums is not straight forward. it mixed all the table before all each field number depend on the table id itself.

anyone who know how to write a good query to select out the field_name pls help :)

`log_list table
[date],[table_id],[field_id],[company_name],...`

my current query :

```
SELECT
date , table_id , name as table_name

FROM
log_list join table_name_list on log_list.table_id = table_name_list.table_id
and log_list.company_name like '%something%'

WHERE
date between @startdate and @enddate
```

thank you for your attention.

Comment: In the future, please use appropriate markup to make code visible as code. I have done this for you, this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tag didn't say what version of SQL Server you are using, assuming you are using 2008+ there is a system function

```
COL_NAME ( table_id , column_id )
```

which if you supply table_id and column_id would get you the name, for detailed reference check it out here: [COL_NAME (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/ms174974(v=sql.100))

If that is not a valid option for you, look closer to sys.columns, the object_id it returns is actually the table's object_id and should be your table_id, so if you do something like following it should work:

```
select C.name AS column_name
...
FROM ...
...
join sys.columns C on yourtable.table_id = C.object_id and yourtable.column_id = C.column_id
```